# How can i pass data to some view file rather send control back to ajax call in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I am making an ajax post request to controller where i fetch some details, now i don't want to send control back to ajax rather i want to pass data to some view.

```
return response()->json(['students' => $students]);
```

instead i want to do like this

return view('frontend.student.leadThanksPage',compact('students'));

ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url:"{{ route('check.student.detail') }}",
  data:$(this).serialize(), 
  success: function(data){ 
 //....... }, 
 error: function(data){ 
//........ }
```

});

and my route is

```
 Route::post('fetch/student/detail', [ 'as'=>'check.student.detail',uses' => 'Frontend\Student\StudentController@fetchStudentDetail' ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can render a view in the Laravel by returning view.

You need to configure the route whether the AJAX request is 'get' or 'post' like below,

```
Route::post('/ajax/GetContent', array(
  'uses'  =>  'AjaxController@loadContent'
));
```

And you can do the implementation in your controller,

```
 public function loadContent(Request $request )
    {
       // you can do your coding
            return view('frontend.student.leadThanksPage')->with('students', $students);
        }

    }
```

Nothing needs to return in your Ajax response.

Happy Coding,
AK

Comment: @shakir add your ajay script in your question for better understanding